# Alexa Developer Console - DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

Brand new to AWS, unsure how to proceed...

**Goal:**
Use a skill to store data using DynamoDB. Reference that data later using Javascript from a webpage.

**Problem:**
In the Alexa developer console (https://developer.amazon.com/), I have my skill code and I have a built-in database (database button from the Code tab). When navigating to that database, I have no permissions to do anything (like get an API key for my webpage). I've created my own account (https://console.aws.amazon.com/) where I have a DynamoDB that I can modify, get a key for, etc. but I am unsure how to link it to my skill.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to follow the following steps:

Add a new file called dbHelpers.js in order to seperate Dynamodb functions from you skill ones. In it you can set code like this:

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const tableName = "questions";

var dbHelper = function () { };
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

dbHelper.prototype.addProduct = (product) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const params = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Item: { 
                'name': "T-shirt"
            }
        };
        docClient.put(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("Unable to insert =>", JSON.stringify(err))
                return reject("Unable to insert");
            }
            // console.log("Saved Data, ", JSON.stringify(data));
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
```

This code is initializing DynamoDB client, with an example of creating new item to DB.
You can read this doc for more info https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.03.html .

Then in your intent, after importing the helper file and setting table name as constant, you can call it like this

```
  return dbHelper.getTrack('0').then((data) => {
    })
```

and add this to you Alexa Skill initialization

```
    .withTableName(dynamoDBTableName)
    .withAutoCreateTable(true)
    .lambda();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing proper IAM role. Or rather trust relationship.

See this guide for more details: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/hosted-skills/alexa-hosted-skills-personal-aws.html